How to calculate the amount of overlap between two polygon shapefiles (both percentage and absolute area) in QGIS
I would like to use QGIS to calculate the amount of overlap between two vector polygon shapefiles, both (1) the percentage of overlap and (2) the absolute area in km^2 (or another unit). When I run Vector overlay -> Intersection (multiple) I just get the absolute parameters of the generated polygons but not relative to the original polygons. I've looked at the previous questions asked here on the GIS Stack Exchange and they are many years out of date, or the guidance is in Arc, or they didn't calculate the percentage overlap


Use the Overlap analysis algorithm. Processing toolbox -> Vector analysis

@BenW this seems to be what I'm looking for but I don't understand the fields in the output shape's attribute table, the documentation you linked to doesn't explain each of them individually. There are 20 rows in the AT but I was expecting just 1 - it appears to be calculating overlap for each of the 20 features but I want the total overlap for all the features together - should I do a dissolve or something? Thanks for the help

The columns are InsideC, OutsideC, dTemp, Ha, layername_area, layername_pc

Yep, dissolving the original polygon layer should work and use that as the input layer for the Overlap analysis and the clipped polygon layer as the overlay layer. The result should be a single feature with additional columns: layername_area & layername_pc which will contain the area and percentage of the original polygon layer which is overlapped by the clipped layer.

Oh I see, the other fields like "InsideC" and "dTemp" were inherited from my specific data. If you post your reply as an answer I'll mark it as the solution
